# Can we say that a "graph is partitioned into 3 subgraphs"?

Tags: phrase-request

Can we say that a "graph is partitioned into 2 subgraphs" ?

My problem is not about the verb, but more on its use with "into"...

What would be the right formulation ?

Comment: You can get a good idea of whether or not people say *partitioned into* by searching a corpus, such as [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/).  (Of course, there's nothing wrong with asking here.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, *into* is the correct preposition here; in fact, any act of division I can think of (*partition, break, divide, split, cut,* etc.) takes *into* when referring to the transformed result ("break into 2 chunks", "cut into little pieces", "partition into 3 subgraphs", and so forth).  Your wording looks fine as it is.